# How to produce the following table faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation, syntax, compile, table

**Question**

Consider a toy function `func[x1,x2,x3,x4]` and a toy grid `gridTot` of the coordinates `x1,x2,x3,x4`:

```
func[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] = 
  If[x3 > x1, 
   1/(x1^2 + 3^2) Exp[-(x1^2 + x3^2)^(1/3.)]*x3/(x3^2 + 20^2) Sin[x2]*
    Cos[10 x2]*x4/(x4 + 50), 0];
gridx1 = Table[x1, {x1, 0.05, 5.1, (5.1 - 0.05)/30}];
gridx2 = Table[20^x2, {x2, -5., Log10[0.05], (Log10[0.05] + 5)/20}];
gridx3 = Table[10^
   x3, {x3, Log10[0.05], Log10[350.], (Log10[350] - Log10[0.05])/50}];
gridx4 = Table[x4, {x4, 38, 88, 2.}];
gridTot = Tuples[{gridx1, gridx2, gridx3, gridx4}];
```

I may produce the table `x1,x2,x3,x4,func[x1,x2,x3,x4]`, where `x1,x2,x3,x4` belong to `gridTot` fast using `Compile`:

```
compiled = 
  Hold@Compile[{{gridTot, _Real, 2}}, 
      Table[{gridTot[[i]][[1]], gridTot[[i]][[2]], gridTot[[i]][[3]], 
        gridTot[[i]][[4]], 
        func[gridTot[[i]][[1]], gridTot[[i]][[2]], gridTot[[i]][[3]], 
         gridTot[[i]][[4]]]}, {i, 1, Length[gridTot], 1}], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
    DownValues@func // ReleaseHold;
functab = compiled[gridTot]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.134968,Null}

Let us now assume that we have the table `functab` instead of `func`, and we want to interpolate it (obtaining `funcInt[x1,x2,x3,x4]`, to produce the table of values `x1,x2,x3,x4,funcint[x1,x2,x3,x4]` for a different grid `gridTot1`:

```
funcInt[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] = 
  Interpolation[functab, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2, x3, x4];
gridx11 = Table[x1, {x1, 0.051, 5.09, (5.09 - 0.051)/30}];
gridx21 = 
  Table[20^x2, {x2, -4.9, Log10[0.049], (Log10[0.049] + 4.9)/20}];
gridx31 = 
  Table[10^x3, {x3, Log10[0.051], Log10[349.], (
    Log10[349.] - Log10[0.051])/50}];
gridx41 = Table[x4, {x4, 38.1, 79.9, 2.}];
gridTot1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{gridx11[[i]], gridx21[[j]], gridx31[[k]], 
     gridx41[[l]]}, {i, 1, Length[gridx11]}, {j, 1, 
     Length[gridx21]}, {k, 1, Length[gridx31]}, {l, 1, 
     Length[gridx41]}], {1, 2, 3, 4}];
```

Now, `Compile` does not work since we are dealing with the interpolation:

```
compiled1 = 
  Hold@Compile[{{gridTot, _Real, 2}}, 
      Table[funcInt[gridTot[[i]][[1]], gridTot[[i]][[2]], 
        gridTot[[i]][[3]], gridTot[[i]][[4]]], {i, 1, Length[gridTot],
         1}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
    DownValues@funcInt // ReleaseHold;
functab1 = compiled1[gridTot1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

just gets stuck. If removing `, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`, it works, but very slow:

```
functab1 = compiled1[gridTot1]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {6.4564,Null}

This means that `Compile` does not handle the interpolation properly. Actually, there is almost no improvement compared to the ordinary code:

```
functab1 = 
   Table[funcInt[gridTot[[i]][[1]], gridTot[[i]][[2]], 
     gridTot[[i]][[3]], gridTot[[i]][[4]]], {i, 1, Length[gridTot], 
     1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {9.9496,Null}

**Question**

Could you please tell me whether there are efficient ways to speedup producing `functab1`? I need to speedup this procedure since in a real case I am dealing with a much larger grid and a much slower interpolated function.

**Update**

I have tried to use `cf2` function for my example:

```
vals = functab[[All, 5]];
xiset1[list_] := Sort[RandomReal[MinMax[list], Length[list]]]
x1set1 = xiset1[gridx1];
x2set1 = xiset1[gridx2];
x3set1 = xiset1[gridx3];
x4set1 = xiset1[gridx4];
xsettot = 
  Flatten[Table[{x1set1[[i]], x2set1[[j]], x3set1[[k]], 
     x4set1[[l]]}, {i, 1, Length[x1set1]}, {j, 1, Length[x2set1]}, {k,
      1, Length[x3set1]}, {l, 1, Length[x4set1]}], {1, 2, 3, 4}];
```

and

```
threadCount = 
  "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. 
     SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
cresult2 = 
   Join @@ cf2[gridx1, gridx2, gridx3, gridx4, vals, xsettot, 
     Range[threadCount], threadCount]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

But it got stuck.

**Update 2**

In case of `cf2`, if I want to make the same function for 3D grid, should I just replace `Plus[...]` with

```
Plus[s1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3],
   s1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3],
   s1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3],
   t1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3],
   s1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3],
   t1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3],
   t1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3],
   t1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 
     1 + i3]]/((s1 + t1) (s2 + t2) (s3 + t3))
      , {k, begin, end}]
```

and remove the block

```
Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
      n = Length[g4];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g4, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g4, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 4];
      If[z <= ga,
       i4 = 1;
       t4 = ga;
       s4 = Compile`GetElement[g4, i4 + 1];
       ,
       If[z >= gb,
         i4 = n - 1;
         t4 = Compile`GetElement[g4, i4];
         s4 = gb;
         ,
         While[b - a > 1,
          c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g4, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
          ];
         i4 = a; t4 = z - ga; s4 = gb - z;
         ];
       ];
      ];
```

apart from removing obvious variables `g4` etc.?

**Update 3**

I have changed `cf2` to interpolate over 3D arrays:

```
D3toD3 = Compile[{{g1, _Real, 1}, {g2, _Real, 1}, {g3, _Real, 
     1}, {y, _Real, 3}, {x, _Real, 
     2}, {threadID, _Integer}, {threadCount, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{jobCount, begin, end, q, r, i1, i2, i3, t1, t2, t3, s1, s2,
      s3}, jobCount = Length[x];
    q = Quotient[jobCount, threadCount];
    r = Mod[jobCount, threadCount];
    begin = 
     q (threadID - 1) + Quotient[r (threadID - 1), threadCount] + 1;
    end = q threadID + Quotient[r threadID, threadCount];
    Table[Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n}, n = Length[g1];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g1, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g1, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 1];
      If[z <= ga, i1 = 1;
       t1 = ga;
       s1 = 0.;, If[z >= gb, i1 = n - 1;
         t1 = 0.;
         s1 = gb;, While[b - a > 1, c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g1, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];];
         i1 = a; t1 = z - ga; s1 = gb - z;];];];
     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n}, n = Length[g2];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g2, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g2, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 2];
      If[z <= ga, i2 = 1;
       t2 = ga;
       s2 = 0.;, If[z >= gb, i2 = n - 1;
         t2 = 0.;
         s2 = gb;, While[b - a > 1, c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g2, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];];
         i2 = a; t2 = z - ga; s2 = gb - z;];];];
     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n}, n = Length[g3];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g3, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g3, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 3];
      If[z <= ga, i3 = 1;
       t3 = ga;
       s3 = 0.;, If[z >= gb, i3 = n - 1;
         t3 = 0.;
         s3 = gb;, While[b - a > 1, c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g3, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];];
         i3 = a; t3 = z - ga; s3 = gb - z;];];];
     Plus[s1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3],
       s1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3],
       s1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3],
       t1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3],
       s1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3],
       t1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3],
       t1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3],
       t1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 
         1 + i3]]/((s1 + t1) (s2 + t2) (s3 + t3))
          , {k, begin, end}]], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Consider a [test data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dul0ch10dvwl8dc/temp-distr.dat?dl=0) `temp_distr.dat`. I define in/out grids `InGrid`, `OutGrid` (the points of the latter belongs to the domain covered by the former) and built-in interpolation:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import["temp-distr.dat", "Table"];
InGridx1 = DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 1]]];
InGridx2 = DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]];
InGridx3 = DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 3]]];
vals = ArrayReshape[
   data[[All, 4]], {Length[InGridx1], Length[InGridx2], 
    Length[InGridx3]}];
OutGridi[list_, n_] := 
 Table[x, {x, Min[list], Max[list], (Max[list] - Min[list])/n}]
OutGridx1 = OutGridi[InGridx1, 50];
OutGridx2 = OutGridi[InGridx2, 50];
OutGridx3 = OutGridi[InGridx3, 130];
OutGrid = Tuples[{OutGridx1, OutGridx2, OutGridx3}];
FuncInt[x1_, x2_, x3_] = 
  Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x1, x2, x3];
```

Finally, I compare the grids produced with `FuncInt` and `D3toD3`:

```
threadCount = 
  "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. 
     SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
outlist1 = 
   Join @@ D3toD3[InGridx1, InGridx2, InGridx3, vals, OutGrid, 
     Range[threadCount], threadCount]; // AbsoluteTiming
outlist2 = FuncInt @@@ OutGrid; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The absolute difference may be very large:

```
Max[Abs[outlist1 - outlist2]]
```

> 0.0122018

**Edit**

Henrik Schumacher has developed the fastest approach, but it requires additional software and hence cannot be used "from box". The approach developed by Lukas Lang is slower but does not require additional soft. For different people, any of them may be preferable.

Comment: Did you check which step is slowing it down? Is it the call to Table? Or is it Flatten? Or is it func?

Comment: @Zatrapilla : it is `func`.

Comment: I think `vals` has the wrong shape. It should be an array of size `{Length[gridx1],Length[gridx2],Length[gridx3],Length[gridx4]}`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : thanks! Then I do not understand how to relate `vals` to the values of `func` (the function from my example), namely `functab[[All,5]]` for the given combination `x1,x2,x3,x4`. And vice versa.

Comment: We have `gridTot == Tuples[{gridx1, gridx2, gridx3, gridx4}]`, right? Then `vals = ArrayReshape[functab[[All,5]],{Length[gridx1],Length[gridx2],Length[gridx3],Length[gridx4]}]` should work.

Comment: Or `vals = Outer[func, gridx1, gridx2, gridx3, gridx4];`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : I have a question about how to use `cf2` for a 3D grid. Could you please look at the updated question (**Update 2**)? Also, comparing the output of `cf2` for the data `functab` from my question (**Update 3**) and the built-in interpolation of this data `funcInt`, I have found that for some points the relative difference between them is 1-2 orders of magnitude, even if the initial and final grids are very similar. Could you please take a look also at this?

Comment: Hm. Could it be that this happened at points outside the original grid? I have just added a fix to `cf2` that corrects some error in that case... Nonetheles,m the result will be different to what _Mathematica_ does outside the grid.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : it seems that for the mentioned 4D example the problem was indeed in the outer grid, thanks! May I please ask you to comment on the discrepancy for the 3D case (where I adapted `cf2` to interpolate over 3D grid) for a particular data (all the relevant code is contained in **Update 3**)?

Comment: Hi John, I finally found the issue. (This took me a while.) The reason was that I handled the boundary points of the function's domain incorrectly. Not only was it susceptible to division by zero, I also accidentally swapped the values for `si` and `ti`. (D'oh.) My tests did not show this because I evaluated the function only on random points in the domain -- so that boundary points never showed up. (Double d'oh.). I hope it works now. Have you tried also the library link version (also updated)? If you tell me your operating system, then I might be able to help you to get it compiled.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : Thanks! It works now. I have not tried the library link version yet. I have Windows 10/11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt to improve further upon @HenrikSchumacher's excellent answer:

```
nd = 4;
cf3 = Module[{xgvars = Unique["xg"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     igvars = Unique["ig"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     tgvars = Unique["tg"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     ivars = Unique["i"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     svars = Unique["s"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     tvars = Unique["t"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd, 
     jvars = Unique["j"] & /@ slist @@ Range@nd}, 
    Inactivate[
       Compile[{seq@{xgvars, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, nd}}, 
        Module[{seq@igvars, seq@tgvars, seq@ivars, seq@svars, 
          seq@tvars}, 
         seq[igvars = 
           Floor[xgvars] - UnitStep[xgvars - indexed@Dimensions@y]];
         seq[tgvars = xgvars - igvars];
         Table[seq[tvars = Compile`GetElement[tgvars, jvars]];
          seq[ivars = Compile`GetElement[igvars, jvars]];
          seq[svars = 1. - tvars];
          
          eval@Total[
            Times @@ #[[All, 1]] Compile`GetElement[y, 
                Sequence @@ #[[All, 2]]] & /@ 
             Tuples@Transpose[{{svars, ivars}, {tvars, 
                 ivars + 1}}, {2, 3, 1}]], 
          seq@{jvars, Length@igvars}]], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"], Except[seq | eval | indexed]] /. 
      seq[expr_] :> 
       RuleCondition@(Sequence @@ 
          Table[Inactivate[expr, 
             Except[slist | indexed]] /. {l_slist :> l[[i]], 
             indexed[l_] :> Inactive[Compile`GetElement][l, i]}, {i, 
            nd}]) /. eval@expr_ :> 
      RuleCondition[Activate[expr /. slist -> List]]] // Activate;

dims = {30, 20, 50, 30};
g = {Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims[[1]]]],
   Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims[[2]]]],
   Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims[[3]]]],
   Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims[[4]]]]};
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims];

f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Tuples[g], Flatten[vals]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

n = 25;
xg = Sort@RandomReal[{#[[1]], #[[-1]]}, n] & /@ g;

result = f @@@ Tuples@xg; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cresult = cf[Sequence @@ g, vals, Tuples@xg]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
threadCount = 
  "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. 
     SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
c2result = 
    Join @@ cf2[Sequence @@ g, vals, Tuples@xg, Range[threadCount], 
      threadCount]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - c2result]]
xig = MapThread[
   Interpolation[
      Transpose@{#, Range@Length@#},
      InterpolationOrder -> 1
      ][#2] &,
   {g, xg}
   ];
c3result = Flatten@cf3[
      Sequence @@ xig,
      vals
      ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - c3result]]
(* 5.06924 *)
(* 0.0531016 *)
(* 0.0504067 *)
(* 5.71765*10^-15 *)
(* 0.0152314 *)
(* 5.71765*10^-15 *)
```

As you can see, `cf3` is even faster than `cf` and `cf2` from @HenrikSchumacher's answer. It also has the advantage that changing the number of dimensions of the interpolation is simply done by changing `nd` (the code takes care to generate the appropriate expression to be compiled). This version epxloits the fact that if we want to interpolate a regular grid `g` onto a regular grid `xg`, we can do the step of finding the appropriate fractional grid indices `xig` only once for each grid axis. The compiled function then gets the lists of fractional grid indices and generates the table inside.

Comment: Thanks! But my attempt in the question body produces the result within the same time.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Hmm, I would have thought it should have made more of a difference... I'll try to see whether I can think of something faster. In the meantime: Why exactly do you need it to be faster? Do you need to run a similar computation repeatedly? If yes, what changes from run to run?

Comment: Please see an update to my question, where I removed the datasets and reformulated the question slightly. I need this procedure to be faster because in the realistic case, I am dealing with much-much larger datasets and grids

Comment: @JohnTaylor Please see the updated answer for an improved version of HenrikSchumacher's answer

Comment: Chapeau! Really clever. =)

Comment: @LukasLang : thank you! Switching between the dimensions is very convenient!

Comment: @LukasLang : I encountered a problem. When trying to apply `cf3` for a 3D interpolation (changing `nd` to 3 previously), I get the error `Argument  ... at position 4 should be a rank 4 tensor of machine-size real numbers`. Could you please tell me what may be a reason?

Comment: Looks like I forgot to replace the 4 in `{y, _Real, 4}` with `nd` (thus the function was still expecting a 4D array of values) - can you try again?

Comment: @LukasLang : thanks! I have just checked the behavior of your implementation for the test data from my question (**Update 3**). Unlike `cf2`, there are no deviations from the values of the built-in interpolated function (please ignore my previous (deleted) comment).

Comment: @LukasLang : because of some problem, `cf3` gets stuck if the grid `xg` includes the boundaries of `g`. How do you think, what may be a problem?

Comment: @JohnTaylor I have updated the answer so that `cf3` now works properly with e.g. `xg=g`. The issue was caused by the interpolation trying to access the grid point after the last, which is now avoided

Comment: @LukasLang : thank you very much for the answer! May I please ask what the most efficient way to use `cf3` for an unstructured grid for fixed `x1` (if I just generate the N rows with random coordinates values) is? Say, for `gfinal[x1_]:=Table[{{x1},RandomReal[MinMax[gridx2]],RandomReal[MinMax[gridx3]],RandomReal[MinMax[gridx4]]},10^5]`. In principle, I may call cf3 for every single point. Of course, I understand that cf3 is not designed for random grids, but anyway.

Comment: For those kinds of grids, @HenrikSchumacher's solution is probably better: I'd expect the speedup due to the compiled index computation to outweigh the slowdown due to the repeated computation of the first index. You could of course try to combine the two strategies for maximum speed

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr: As always with my post, find the most recent implementation at the bottom of the post.

`InterpolationFunction`s are indeed much less efficient than they could/should be. Here is a compiled implementation of a scalar interpolation function in four variables with linear interpolation in each direction. It is designed for random access and for rectangular, but irregularly spaced grids. It finds the correct grid point via binary search in each dimension. Moreover, it is `Listable` and parallelized.

```
cf = Compile[{{g1, _Real, 1}, {g2, _Real, 1}, {g3, _Real, 1}, {g4, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 4}, {x, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{i1, i2, i3, i4, t1, t2, t3, t4, s1, s2, s3, s4},
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g1];
     a = 1; ga = Compile`GetElement[g1, a];
     b = n; gb = Compile`GetElement[g1, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, 1];
     If[z <= ga,
      i1 = 1; t1 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i1 = n - 1; t1 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g1, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i1 = a; t1 = (z - ga)/(gb - ga);
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g2];
     a = 1; ga = Compile`GetElement[g2, a];
     b = n; gb = Compile`GetElement[g2, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, 2];
     If[z <= ga,
      i2 = 1; t2 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i2 = n - 1; t2 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g2, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i2 = a; t2 = (z - ga)/(gb - ga);
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g3];
     a = 1; ga = Compile`GetElement[g3, a];
     b = n; gb = Compile`GetElement[g3, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, 3];
     If[z <= ga,
      i3 = 1; t3 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i3 = n - 1; t3 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g3, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i3 = a; t3 = (z - ga)/(gb - ga);
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g4];
     a = 1; ga = Compile`GetElement[g4, a];
     b = n; gb = Compile`GetElement[g4, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, 4];
     If[z <= ga,
      i4 = 1; t4 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i4 = n - 1; t4 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g4, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i4 = a; t4 = (z - ga)/(gb - ga);
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    s1 = (1. - t1);
    s2 = (1. - t2);
    s3 = (1. - t3);
    s4 = (1. - t4);
    
    Plus[
     s1 s2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3, i4],
     s1 s2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3, 1 + i4],
     s1 s2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3, i4],
     s1 s2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
     s1 t2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3, i4],
     s1 t2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3, 1 + i4],
     s1 t2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, i4],
     s1 t2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
     t1 s2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3, i4],
     t1 s2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3, 1 + i4],
     t1 s2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3, i4],
     t1 s2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
     t1 t2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3, i4],
     t1 t2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3, 1 + i4], 
     t1 t2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, i4], 
     t1 t2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4]
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Here is a usage and test example:

```
dims = {30, 20, 50, 30};
g = Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, #]] & /@ dims;
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dims];

f = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Tuples[g, Flatten[vals]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

n = 1000000;
x = Transpose[RandomReal[{#[[1]], #[[-1]]}, n] & /@ g];

result = f @@@ x; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cresult = cf[Sequence @@ g, vals, x]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - cresult]]

8.33928

0.100488

7.77156*10^-16
```

So it seems to produce essentially the correct results with an 80-fold speedup.

This is certainly not optimal. For one, the fine grained parallelization probably leads to some avoidable overhead. Moreover, as OP wants to apply this interpolation to a presorted list of points, one could first search a neighborhood of the previously found grid point and do the binary search only if this is not successful. Quite likely, this would be way more cache friendly and thus faster.

**Edit**

Here is an improved version of the above. It gets rid of 3 out of 4 divisions (which does not seem to matter much) and has improved parallelism.

```
cf2 = Compile[{{g1, _Real, 1}, {g2, _Real, 1}, {g3, _Real, 1}, {g4, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 4}, {x, _Real, 2}, {threadID, _Integer}, {threadCount, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{jobCount, begin, end, q, r, i1, i2, i3, i4, t1, t2, t3, t4, s1, s2, s3, s4},
    
    jobCount = Length[x];
    q = Quotient[jobCount, threadCount];
    r = Mod[jobCount, threadCount];
    begin = q (threadID - 1) + Quotient[r (threadID - 1), threadCount] + 1;
    end = q threadID + Quotient[r threadID, threadCount];
    
    Table[
     
     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
      n = Length[g1];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g1, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g1, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 1];
      If[z <= ga,
       i1 = a;
       s1 = 1.;
       t1 = 0.;
       ,
       If[z >= gb,
         i1 = b - 1;
         s1 = 0.;
         t1 = 1.;
         ,
         While[b - a > 1,
          c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g1, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
          ];
         i1 = a; t1 = z - ga; s1 = gb - z;
         ];
       ];
      ];

     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
      n = Length[g2];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g2, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g2, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 2];
      If[z <= ga,
       i2 = a;
       s2 = 1.;
       t2 = 0.;
       ,
       If[z >= gb,
         i2 = b - 1;
         s2 = 0.;
         t2 = 1.;
         ,
         While[b - a > 1,
          c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g2, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
          ];
         i2 = a; t2 = z - ga; s2 = gb - z;
         ];
       ];
      ];

     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
      n = Length[g3];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g3, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g3, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 3];
      If[z <= ga,
       i3 = a;
       s3 = 1.;
       t3 = 0.;
       ,
       If[z >= gb,
         i3 = b - 1;
         s3 = 0.;
         t3 = 1.;
         ,
         While[b - a > 1,
          c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g3, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
          ];
         i3 = a; t3 = z - ga; s3 = gb - z;
         ];
       ];
      ];

     Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
      n = Length[g4];
      a = 1;
      b = n;
      ga = Compile`GetElement[g4, a];
      gb = Compile`GetElement[g4, b];
      z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 4];
      If[z <= ga,
       i4 = a;
       s4 = 1.;
       t4 = 0.;
       ,
       If[z >= gb,
         i4 = b - 1;
         s4 = 0.;
         t4 = 1.;
         ,
         While[b - a > 1,
          c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
          gc = Compile`GetElement[g4, c];
          If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
          ];
         i4 = a; t4 = z - ga; s4 = gb - z;
         ];
       ];
      ];
     Plus[
       s1 s2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3, i4],
       s1 s2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3, 1 + i4],
       s1 s2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3, i4],
       s1 s2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
       s1 t2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3, i4],
       s1 t2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3, 1 + i4],
       s1 t2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, i4], 
       s1 t2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
       t1 s2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3, i4],
       t1 s2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3, 1 + i4],
       t1 s2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3, i4], 
       t1 s2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4],
       t1 t2 s3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3, i4],
       t1 t2 s3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3, 1 + i4], 
       t1 t2 t3 s4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, i4], 
       t1 t2 t3 t4 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3, 1 + i4]
       ]/((s1 + t1) (s2 + t2) (s3 + t3) (s4 + t4)),
     {k, begin, end}
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

It has a slightly different syntax; call it like this:

```
threadCount = "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
cresult2 =  Join @@ cf2[Sequence @@ g, vals, x, Range[threadCount], threadCount];
```

It is roughly twice as fast as the preceding version, thus 160 times as fast as the `InterpolationFunction`. But still, 80% of runtime seem to go into the binary search...

**Edit 3**

This is probably over the top, but I was curious and implemented the above approach based on binary search directly in C++. Using LibraryLink as a jit-compiler, it can handle arbitrary-dimensional multivariate functions (and also vector-valued functions).

If you want to run this, then you might have to adjust the path `dirOpenMP` to your local installation of OpenMP and the settings for `"CompileOptions"`.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

(*Path to local OpenMP installation. This should work for OpenMP installed via homebrew on Apple Silicon.*)
dirOpenMP = "/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp";

Quiet[Cases[DownValues[cInterpolate], HoldPattern[_ :> x_LibraryFunction] :> LibraryFunctionUnload[x]]];
ClearAll[cInterpolate];
cInterpolate[DomDim_Integer, AmbDim_Integer] := 
  cInterpolate[DomDim, AmbDim] = Module[{lib, code, name},
    name = "cInterpolate_" <> IntegerString[DomDim] <> "_" <> 
      IntegerString[AmbDim];
    code = StringJoin["

#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

#include \"mathlink.h\"

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"


template<typename Int, typename Int1, typename Int2>
Int JobPointer( const Int job_count, const Int1 thread_count, const Int2 k )
{
    return job_count/static_cast<Int>(thread_count)*static_cast<Int>(k) + \
job_count%static_cast<Int>(thread_count)*static_cast<Int>(k)/static_cast<Int>(thread_count);
}

template< size_t DomDim, size_t AmbDim, typename Scal_in_, typename Scal_out_>
class Interpolator
{
    // DomDim   - domain dimension
    // AmbDim   - ambient dimension (dimension of the target space)
    // Scal_in_ - scalar type for the inputs
    // Scal_in_ - scalar type for the outputs
    
    static_assert(DomDim >= 1);
    
    static_assert(AmbDim >= 1);
    
public:
    
    using Int           = size_t;
    using Scal_in       = Scal_in_;
    using Scal_out      = Scal_out_;
    
    using Index_T       = std::array<Int,DomDim>;
    
    using KnotVector_T  = const Scal_in *;
    using Grid_T        = std::array<KnotVector_T,DomDim>;
    
    using Input_T       = std::array<Scal_in, DomDim>;
    using Output_T      = std::array<Scal_out,AmbDim>;
    
    static constexpr Int corner_count = (1 << DomDim);
    
protected:

    Index_T dims;
    Grid_T  grid;
    
    const   Scal_out * const      values;
    
    mutable Index_T               grid_idx = {0};
    
    mutable std::array<Input_T,2> t = {{{0},{1}}};
    mutable Input_T               x = {0};
    mutable Output_T              y = {0};
    
public:
    
    Interpolator( const Grid_T & grid_, const Index_T & dims_, const Scal_out * const values_ )
    :   grid(grid_)
    ,   dims(dims_)
    ,   values(values_)
    {}
    
    template< typename I>
    Interpolator( const Scal_in * const * const grid_, const I * const dims_, const Scal_out * const values_ )
    :   values(values_)
    {
        std::copy( &dims_[0], &dims_[DomDim], &dims[0] );
        std::copy( &grid_[0], &grid_[DomDim], &grid[0] );
    }
    
    void Evaluate( const Scal_in * const x_, Scal_out * const y_ )
    {
        Read(x_);
        Find();
        Eval();
        Write(y_);
    }
    
    const Index_T & GridIndex() const
    {
        return grid_idx;
    }

    Int GlobalIndex( const Index_T & idx ) const
    {
        if constexpr( DomDim == 1 )
        {
            return idx[0];
        }
        else
        {
            Int global_idx = 0;
            
            for( Int k = 0; k < DomDim - 1; ++k )
            {
                global_idx = (global_idx + idx[k]) * dims[k+1];
            }
            
            global_idx += idx[DomDim-1];

            return global_idx;
        }
    }
    
    void Read( const Scal_in * const x_ )
    {
        std::copy( &x_[0], &x_[DomDim], &x[0] );
    }
    
    void Write( Scal_out * const y_ ) const
    {
        std::copy( &y[0], &y[AmbDim], &y_[0] );
    }
    
    void Eval()
    {
        Scal_in volume = static_cast<Scal_in>(1);
        
        for( Int k = 0; k < DomDim; ++k )
        {
            volume *= t[0][k] + t[1][k];
        }
        
        const Scal_in volume_inv = static_cast<Scal_in>(1) / volume;
        
        std::fill( &y[0], &y[AmbDim], static_cast<Scal_out>(0) );
        
        for( Int kdx = 0; kdx < corner_count; ++kdx )
        {
            // For each corner of the grid cuboid, we have to find the global position `global_idx` of the corner in the grid and its coeffcient `coeff`
        
            Index_T idx = grid_idx;
            
            Scal_in coeff = volume_inv;
            
            for( Int k = 0; k < DomDim; ++k )
            {
                Int bit  = (kdx >> (DomDim-1-k)) & 1;
                idx[k]  += bit;
                coeff   *= t[bit][k];
            }
            
            const Int global_idx = AmbDim * GlobalIndex(idx);
            
            auto coeff_converted = static_cast<Scal_out>(coeff);
            
            for( Int k = 0; k < AmbDim; ++k )
            {
                y[k] += coeff_converted * values[global_idx+k];
            }
        }
    }
    
    void Find( const Scal_in z, const Int k )
    {
        KnotVector_T g = grid[k];
    
        Int a = 0;
        Int b = dims[k]-1;
        
        Scal_in g_a = g[a];
        Scal_in g_b = g[b];
        
        if( z < g_a )
        {
            grid_idx[k] = a;
            t[0][k]     = static_cast<Scal_in>(1);
            t[1][k]     = static_cast<Scal_in>(0);
            
            
        }
        else if ( z > g_b )
        {
            grid_idx[k] = b-1;
            t[0][k]     = static_cast<Scal_in>(0);
            t[1][k]     = static_cast<Scal_in>(1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Binary search
            while( b > a + 1 )
            {
                Int     c   = a + (b-a)/2;
                Scal_in g_c = g[c];
                
                if( z <= g_c )
                {
                    b   = c;
                    g_b = g_c;
                }
                else
                {
                    a   = c;
                    g_a = g_c;
                }
            }
        
            grid_idx[k] = a;
            t[0][k]     = g_b - z;
            t[1][k]     = z - g_a;
            
        }
    }
        
    void Find()
    {
        for( Int k = 0; k < DomDim; ++k )
        {
            Find( x[k], k );
        }
    }
    
}; // class Interpolator

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int " <> name <> 
       "(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    constexpr size_t DomDim = ", IntegerString[DomDim], ";
    constexpr size_t AmbDim = ", IntegerString[AmbDim], ";

    std::vector<mint>   dims (DomDim);
    std::vector<mreal*> grid (DomDim);

    for( size_t k = 0; k < DomDim; ++k )
    {
        MTensor g = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[k]);

        dims[k] = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(g)[0];
        grid[k] = libData->MTensor_getRealData(g);
    }

    MTensor vals = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[DomDim  ]);
    MTensor x_   = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[DomDim+1]);
    MTensor y_   = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[DomDim+2]);

    size_t thread_count = MArgument_getInteger(Args[DomDim+3]);

    const mreal * const x = libData->MTensor_getRealData(x_);
          mreal * const y = libData->MTensor_getRealData(y_);

    const size_t n = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(x_)[0];

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( thread_count )
    for( size_t thread = 0; thread < thread_count; ++thread )
    {
        Interpolator<DomDim,AmbDim,mreal,mreal> f ( &grid[0], &dims[0], libData->MTensor_getRealData(vals) );

        const size_t i_begin = JobPointer( n, thread_count, thread   );
        const size_t i_end   = JobPointer( n, thread_count, thread+1 );

        for( size_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i )
        {
            f.Evaluate( &x[DomDim*i], &y[AmbDim*i] );
        }
    }
    
    libData->MTensor_disown(y_);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}"];
    lib = CreateLibrary[code, name, "Language" -> "C++", 
      "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print,(*"ShellCommandFunction"->Print,*)
      "CompileOptions" -> {" -Wall", "-Wextra", 
        "-Wno-unused-parameter", "-mmacosx-version-min=12.0", 
        "-std=c++20", "-Ofast", "-flto", "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp", 
        "-lomp", "-framework mathlink"}, 
      "IncludeDirectories" -> {FileNameJoin[{dirOpenMP, "include"}]}, 
      "LibraryDirectories" -> {FileNameJoin[{dirOpenMP, "lib"}]}
      ];
    LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, name,
     {
      Sequence @@ ConstantArray[{Real, 1, "Constant"}, DomDim],
      {Real, DomDim + Boole[AmbDim != 1], "Constant"},
      {Real, 2, "Constant"},
      If[AmbDim == 1, {Real, 1, "Shared"}, {Real, 2, "Shared"}],
      Integer
      },
     "Void"
     ]];

Interpolate[grids_, vals_, x_] := 
  Module[{threadCount, DomDim, AmbDim, y},
   threadCount = 
    "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. 
       SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
   DomDim = Length[grids];
   y = ConstantArray[0., {Length[x]}];
   AmbDim = 
    If[TensorRank[vals] == DomDim, 1, 
     Dimensions[vals][[DomDim + 1]]];
   cInterpolate[DomDim, AmbDim][Sequence @@ grids, vals, x, y, 
    threadCount];
   y
   ];
```

Here a brief test:

```
y = Interpolate[g, vals, x]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - y]]
```

> 0.00973586
>
> 6.66134*10^-16

This is more than nine times faster than `cf2` and more than 800 times faster than the `InterpolationFunction`.

**Edit 4**

Here is a 3D-version of `cf2`.

```
D3toD3 = Compile[{{g1, _Real, 1}, {g2, _Real, 1}, {g3, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 3}, {x, _Real, 2}, {threadID, _Integer}, {threadCount, _Integer}},
   Module[{jobCount, begin, end, q, r, i1, i2, i3, t1, t2, t3, s1, s2, s3},
   
   jobCount = Length[x];
   
   q = Quotient[jobCount, threadCount];
   r = Mod[jobCount, threadCount];
   begin = q (threadID - 1) + Quotient[r (threadID - 1), threadCount] + 1;
   end = q threadID + Quotient[r threadID, threadCount];
   
   Table[

    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g1];
     a = 1;
     b = n;
     ga = Compile`GetElement[g1, a];
     gb = Compile`GetElement[g1, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 1];
     If[z <= ga,
      i1 = a;
      s1 = 1.;
      t1 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i1 = b - 1;
        s1 = 0.;
        t1 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g1, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i1 = a; s1 = gb - z; t1 = z - ga;
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g2];
     a = 1;
     b = n;
     ga = Compile`GetElement[g2, a];
     gb = Compile`GetElement[g2, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 2];
     If[z <= ga,
      i2 = a;
      s2 = 1.;
      t2 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i2 = b - 1;
        s2 = 0.;
        t2 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g2, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i2 = a; s2 = gb - z; t2 = z - ga;
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Block[{a, ga, b, gb, c, gc, z, n},
     n = Length[g3];
     a = 1;
     b = n;
     ga = Compile`GetElement[g3, a];
     gb = Compile`GetElement[g3, b];
     z = Compile`GetElement[x, k, 3];
     If[z <= ga,
      i3 = a;
      s3 = 1.;
      t3 = 0.;
      ,
      If[z >= gb,
        i3 = b - 1;
        s3 = 0.;
        t3 = 1.;
        ,
        While[b - a > 1,
         c = Quotient[a + b, 2];
         gc = Compile`GetElement[g3, c];
         If[z <= gc, b = c; gb = gc;, a = c; ga = gc];
         ];
        i3 = a; s3 = gb - z; t3 = z - ga;
        ];
      ];
     ];
    
    Plus[
      s1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, i3],
      s1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, i2, 1 + i3],
      s1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, i3],
      s1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3],
      t1 s2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, i3],
      t1 s2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, i2, 1 + i3],
      t1 t2 s3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, i3],
      t1 t2 t3 Compile`GetElement[y, 1 + i1, 1 + i2, 1 + i3]
      ]/((s1 + t1) (s2 + t2) (s3 + t3))
    , {k, begin, end}]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! First, a side question: is it possible to use the interpolation you have implemented for the numerical integration? If yes, then should we expect a speedup of the integration compared to the standard `Interpolation`?

Comment: Maybe. My functions are optimized for bulk evaluation, but `NIntegrate` prefers to evaluate functions one at a time for adaptive quadrature rules. Nonetheless, `cf` or a wrapper like `F = {x1, x2, x3, x4} |-> cf[g1, g2, g3, g4, vals, {x1, x2, x3, x4}];` might work quite fine.

Comment: Thanks again. I have faced a problem: when trying to use `cf2` for my example from the question, it got stuck (please see an update to the question). The same is the case for `cf`. What do you think, what may be the problem?

Comment: Your solution helps amazingly! Could you please tell me one thing? In your last implementation, what is `g`?

Comment: Ooops. `g = {g1, g2, g3, g4}`. (I replaced it.)