# Speed up Interpolation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation, compile

I have to calculate a lot of values using interpolation function. I think it could be faster, but I wasn't able to speed it up any way using Compile/Parallel computations. Am I missing something?

```
Y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10000];
X = Range[10000];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{X, Y}], InterpolationOrder -> 9];
x = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, 10^6];
ans = f /@ x; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This takes about 2 seconds. I know interpolation is not a function that can be compiled, so this isn't working faster:

```
fc = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, f[x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

Neither does this:

```
ParallelTable[f[x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

I asked ChatGPT4 and it offered this:

```
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[f, x];
ansParallel = ParallelMap[f, x]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Which takes 1 second. Is there a way to use to speed this up?

Comment: Using `Method -> "Spline"` and `ans = f[x]` instead of `ans2 = f /@ x` helps a but (factor 3). But in general, `InterpolationFunction`s are incredibly slow in _Mathematica_. See also `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283713/38178` for an example with interpolation order 1 and much much faster it could be.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher so the best way here is to write whatever order I need using compilable functions?

Comment: Yeah, it's a nightmare! =/ As you can see in the other post, I have already developed a C++ class that can do the lookup of the argument in the grid of the interpolation function. Adding B-spline interpolation should be doable. I have already started to research the details...

Comment: Could you correct the first snippet of your code? It gives errors: Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,<<9990>>},Y} cannot be transposed, and so on

Comment: @rych sorry, the first line with a definition of Y was eaten by code box markup.

Answer (score 2):

Using the derivatives at the nodes speeds up the interpolation by a factor of two, but at a cost:

```
Y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10000];
X = N@Range[10000];
ff = Interpolation[Transpose[{X, Y}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 9]; // AbsoluteTiming
f = Interpolation[
    Transpose[{
      List /@ X,
      Y, ff'[X], ff''[X], ff'''[X], ff''''[X]}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 9]; // AbsoluteTiming
x = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, 10^6];
ans = f@x; // AbsoluteTiming (* pass list instead of Map *)
(*
  {0.012657, Null} (* first interpolation cost *)
  {0.199812, Null} (* one-time cost of derivative values *)
  {0.954995, Null} (* 10^6 interpolations *)
*)
```

Check equivalence:

```
foo = ff /@ x;
foo == ans
(*  True  *)
```

(The five function/derivative values at each node determine the ten coefficients of the degree-9 interpolant.)