# What can be improved in the following custom interpolation?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, interpolation, data, compile

Consider some test data: a grid of x, y, and values of some function on this grid:

```
func[x_, y_] = 
  Exp[-((y - 5)/(10.*Cos[x]^4))] ((Sin[x] Cos[x]^5)/y^2 + Sin[x]^2/(
     y^6 + 1) + Sin[x]*Cos[x]^4);
gridx = Table[10^x, {x, -5., Log10[0.2], (Log10[0.2] + 5.)/30}];
gridy = Table[10^
   x, {x, Log10[0.05], Log10[150], (Log10[150] - Log10[0.05])/80}];
{xminmax, yminmax} = MinMax[#] & /@ {gridx, gridy};
grid = Tuples[{gridx, gridy}];
distrvals = func @@@ grid;
data = Join[grid, Partition[distrvals, 1], 2];
```

I would like to "map" it onto random points belonging to the domain within the grid:

```
nev = 10^6;
{xrand, yrand} = RandomReal[#, nev] & /@ {xminmax, yminmax};
randompts = Join[Partition[xrand, 1], Partition[yrand, 1], 2];
```

The straightforward but slow way is to use built-in `Interpolation`:

```
intBuiltIn[x_, y_] = 
 Exp[Interpolation[Log[data], InterpolationOrder -> 1][Log[x], 
   Log[y]]]
vals1 = intBuiltIn @@@ randompts; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.15255,Null}

Here, I interpolated the logarithmized data to account for the structure of the initial grid and the exponential behavior of the initial function. This way is very slow, so I want to speed up it. I implement a bilinear compilable interpolation:

```
linint = 
 Compile[{{xlogrand, _Real}, {ylogrand, _Real}, {gridxlog, _Real, 
    1}, {gridylog, _Real, 
    1}, {nearestindexx, _Integer}, {nearestindexy, _Integer}, \
{distrlog, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{xel, yel, x1, x2, y1, y2, z11, z21, z12, 
    z22, \[CapitalDelta], leny, indexlargerx, indexlargery},
   (*Finding the index of the grids with the elements larged than the \
given random point*)
   xel = Compile`GetElement[gridxlog, nearestindexx];
   indexlargerx = nearestindexx + UnitStep[xlogrand - xel];
   yel = Compile`GetElement[gridylog, nearestindexy];
   indexlargery = nearestindexy + UnitStep[ylogrand - yel];
   (*The two points x1, x2 with x1 < x < x2*)
   x1 = Compile`GetElement[gridxlog, indexlargerx - 1];
   x2 = Compile`GetElement[gridxlog, indexlargerx];
   y1 = Compile`GetElement[gridylog, indexlargery - 1];
   y2 = Compile`GetElement[gridylog, indexlargery];
   (*Corresponding values of the function*)
   leny = Length[gridylog];
   z11 = 
    Compile`GetElement[
     distrlog, (indexlargerx - 2)*leny + indexlargery - 1];
   z21 = 
    Compile`GetElement[
     distrlog, (indexlargerx - 1)*leny + indexlargery - 1];
   z12 = 
    Compile`GetElement[
     distrlog, (indexlargerx - 2)*leny + indexlargery];
   z22 = 
    Compile`GetElement[
     distrlog, (indexlargerx - 1)*leny + indexlargery];
   \[CapitalDelta] = (x2 - x1) (y2 - y1);
   Exp[(*{xlogrand,x1,x2,ylogrand,y1,y2,z11,z21,z12,
    z22,*)((x2 - xlogrand)*(y2 - ylogrand))/\[CapitalDelta]*
      z11 + ((xlogrand - x1)*(y2 - 
         ylogrand))/\[CapitalDelta] z21 + ((x2 - xlogrand) (ylogrand -
          y1))/\[CapitalDelta]*
      z12 + ((xlogrand - x1) (ylogrand - y1))/((x2 - x1) (y2 - y1))
       z22(*}*)]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

and then use `Nearest`:

```
(*Logarithmized grids and random points*)
{gridxlog, gridylog, xlogrand, ylogrand, distrlog} = 
   Log[#] & /@ {gridx, gridy, xrand, yrand, 
     distrvals}; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Finding the element of the grid which is nearest to the random \
points*)
nearestx = Nearest[gridxlog -> "Index"];
nearesty = Nearest[gridylog -> "Index"];
nearestindexx = nearestx[xlogrand] // Flatten; // AbsoluteTiming
nearestindexy = nearesty[ylogrand] // Flatten; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Once I create `nearestx`, `nearesty` (this has to be done only once), the approach is more than 100 times faster than with using the built-in interpolation:

```
vals2 = linint[xlogrand, ylogrand, gridxlog, gridylog, nearestindexx, 
    nearestindexy, distrlog]; // AbsoluteTiming
Abs[(vals2 - vals1)/vals1] // Max
```

> {0.0328157,Null}

> 1.77041*10^-14

What may be improved in this algorithm? Can it be made faster?

Comment: So your grid _is_ structured: It is product grid. So you can use simple, independent binary searches for the x and y coordinates. This would allow you to circumvent the complicated handling of `Nearest`'s output. Not sure whether that will be faster.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : how do you think, if I have the initial data in the form `{x,y,z,pdf[x,y,z]}` and want to map it to `pdf[X,xrand,yrand]`, where `X` is some point within the domain of definition of `x` and `xrand`, `yrand` are random points, would it be efficient to use first one of the methods from the question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282637/how-to-produce-the-following-table-faster to map `x,y,z,pdf[x,y,z]` $\to$ `y,z,pdf[X,y,z]` and then the interpolation from this question?

Comment: Phh.... don't know. I actually don't understand what you want to do. Sorry. When in doubt, code both approaches and _measure_ the performance.